# Layover in Canada from US under COVID regulations

Tags: usa, transit, canada, layovers, covid-19

The main question is, regardless of nationality and reason for travels, are travelers from the US allowed to transit through a Canadian airport (for <24 h and within the secure transit area) to a third country (EU)?

https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/border#transit-air

> You may be permitted to transit through Canada to reach another country.

Where may could be interpreted in several ways. It also stipulates that:

> **While travelling**
> You must follow all flight requirements and comply with any guidelines provided by the Airport Authority.

with a link to:

https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/flying#health-check

which links to a checklist that is very specific for people that actually want to *enter* Canada.
It feels safe to me to assume that, **regardless** of nationality, travelers from the US (and only the US?) are allowed to transit without completing any additional testing or checklists, with no visa or ArriveCAN.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, Canada does not have a general policy allowing visa-free transit (even if you remain in the international transit area). If your nationality and itinerary [require a transit visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/eligibility.html) pre-Covid, you need a visa under Covid rules as well.**

> travelers from the US (and only the US?)

The [transit exception](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/coronavirus-covid19/travel-restrictions-exemptions.html#exempt) applies to all foreign nationals departing from countries other than the US, as long as they remain in the sterile transit area **and** are travelling for a non-discretionary purpose.

> The exemptions under the Orders do not apply to foreign nationals travelling for optional or discretionary purposes. The onus is on the foreign national to demonstrate the purpose of their travel.
>
> https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/service-delivery/coronavirus/travel-restrictions.html#purpose

The onus is on the foreign national to establish that the travel is [non-discretionary](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/service-delivery/coronavirus/travel-restrictions/non-optional-non-discretionary.html) (e.g. work, study, assisting a family member).

**For persons travelling from the US, as long as the purpose of travel is non-discretionary, they may enter Canada for transit purposes.**

> Examples of other non-optional or non-discretionary travel:
> [...]
>
> transiting through Canada for non-optional or non-discretionary purposes
>
> https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/service-delivery/coronavirus/travel-restrictions/non-optional-non-discretionary.html

There is no requirement to stay within the sterile area if you come from the US, *but* if you leave the area, you become subject to possible public health measures.

If you cannot demonstrate that you are travelling for a non-discretionary purpose, you may be denied entry/transit regardless if you come from the US or not.

> are allowed to transit without completing any additional testing or checklists

For passengers staying within the sterile area, ArriveCAN is required for transit passengers, but pre-arrival test may be exempted. You are also exempted from arrival testing, hotel stopover and quarantine if you remain in the transit area. (See rubric "Transit" at https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/exemptions).

If you intend to leave the transit area (or must do so because  of your flight itinerary), then you may be required to be tested and subject to quarantine until your next flight. So you should inquire with the airlines and the airport for the exact itinerary.

Comment: On the other hand, the website specifies that it is not allowed to transit to a domestic flight. If flights to a third country are not allowed (because you would pass through immigration) and to Canada are not allowed (as mentioned before), this would render the whole thing void of purpose, as no flights would be allowed. Except possibly flights from the US to the US through Canada?

Comment: @vf_mmg International (non-Canada/US) to US or International to International are possible within sterile areas. Canadian airports are designed so that US sectors are separated because of pre-clearance (although for now Canada has not implemented pre-clearance in US).

Comment: Thank you @xngtng. I have accepted your answer. I believe the website should be much clearer, because it is entirely unclear how those areas are separated and, without your knowledge, I would have wasted a decent amount of money and lost my chance to travel.

Comment: Just because you have to go through Canadian immigration does not mean you cannot remain in the transit area. Both the [Transit Without Visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/without-visa/eligibility.html) and [China Transit Program](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/without-visa/china-transit-eligibility.html) programs allow transit to/from the US for nationals of certain countries, if they remain in the international transit area. And this applies in both directions.

Comment: @user102008 You are right. I asked CBSA and updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @vf_mmg Please see my updated answer; if you are travelling for a non-discretionary purpose and you do not need a visa ordinarily, you can transit in Canada. My apologies for misinformation earlier.

Comment: @xngtng I appreciate your edit and your comment! I had already canceled my tickets as I had missed several things already. The non-discretionary reason part still seems really poorly explained to me, it is not mentioned anywhere in the main page, but only in the page you linked, which makes it really strange. And that page was update 7 months before the one I posted, so it might be not up to date?
It might be that transit for discretionary trips is allowed now?